# Блокировка загрузки изображений

Tags: android

Есть ли варианты полностью заблокировать загрузку изображений из интернета на Android устройстве?

Мне нужно на устройстве только текстовое содержимое, остальное по задаче - лишний расход трафика (соответственно потеря в производительности).

Comment: а как вы эти картинки грузите? просто уберите код который грузит и всё. картинка ж изначально это ссылка в json'e. она без ваших усилий сама никак не загрузится

Comment: Имееться в виду заблокировать на всем устройстве. Браузеры, маркет, сторонние приложения.

Comment: @PavelNastoburko это можно сделать - единственное вам прийдется писать свой анализатор трафика ... используя VPN Service

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы имеете ввиду в браузере, то
можно с помощью [Opera Mini](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.mini.native&hl=ru).
Открываете **"Настройки" > "Экономия трафика" > Вместо "Автоматический" ставите "Экстремальный" и выбираете "Изображение" > "Выкл."**

Comment: не в браузере. Во всех приложениях